# CSS: Setting styles on form or main content not working (but inside)

Tags: html, css, forms

I am new to CSS and hope someone can help me with this.

I have an HTML page that contains an HTML form with the below structure.

Everything works fine so far but for some reason **I am unable to apply certain styles to the "main" section or the form**, esp. a border or a background-color style.

I tried adding some of the following to both the section and the form and both using IDs and classes, with no effect - even if I add `!important`:

- `border: 1px solid #000;`
- `background-color: #ccc;`

**The only thing I am able to set on the above is a margin which works.**

However, if I set border or background styles to the inner divs (e.g. for class "frmLine") it works just fine so my guess is that for some reason the inner styles are overlapping any styles applied to the parenting form and section.

**Can someone tell me how I can resolve this ?**
Could the reason be that there is no margin or padding between the parenting section / form and the inner divs ?

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php require_once("includes/menu.php"); ?>
    <section id="main">
        <form id="frmRequest">
            <div class="col-12">
                <span class="frmTitle">Some title</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 frmLine">
                <div class="col-3 frmCaption">Some caption</div>
                <div class="col-9">Some form field</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 frmLine">
                <!-- ... -->
```

**My CSS (relevant styles):**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto -140px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 0 140px;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid #000; /* This is what is not working ! */
    margin-left: 8.33%;
    margin-right: 8.33%;
}
.frmCaption {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.frmField {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.frmLine {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Update:** 
I did some further testing which showed this is caused by the CSS. I then removed all styles and re-added them step by step which showed that the issue is caused by my grid styles (see below), specifically by the floating styles on them. **As soon as I add these styles the border around the main section disappears resp. gets moved above the section** - can someone tell me how I can fix this ?

```
/* ... */
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}   
.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: Try without .wrapper class styles and see

Comment: Thanks - that's messing up my page since I use this for the general layout  and to cover for the footer etc.

Comment: check the CSS Specificity if you are missing something or some other selector has a higher specificty than yours like - an id with tag selector (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: Try this :
border: solid #000;
border-width: 1px;

Comment: @Sagar: Thanks. I removed the wrapper styles completely for testing but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: No keep wrapper and use above border css I said for #main

Comment: @Sagar: Thanks - The border styles you provided are the same as I have, just applied separately, no ? However, I tried this and it then only shows me a top-border which seems to appear as 2px instead of 1px. Same if I apply it as an inline style.

Comment: I copied over your code to jsfiddle and it works just fine for me. Please check for any missing details, you might want to try runnable code snippets: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to show us.

Comment: @BillyNate: Thanks for that ! @ All: Just a little update: I played around with this and it seems that it displays my main section above the inner form instead of around it which is why the 1px border appears as a 2px line (I guess it then just shows a top and bottom border for this with no content). So perhaps this is with the HTML, not the CSS ? Any ideas why it could move the section above the form instead of around it ?

Comment: Update: The issue is definitely with the CSS. So I removed all styles and will add them in part by part to see which one is causing this. Will update the post then.

Comment: @BillyNate: I updated my post with what I found during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the default value for the `overflow` of (most of the, if not all) `block` level elements (being `visible`) causes the overflowing elements to be visible, but the element itself to not adjust its own size. By setting the `overflow` to `hidden` the element does adjust its own size.

```css
#main {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left: 8.33%;
    margin-right: 8.33%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I spent ages on this and couldn't figure it out but this does the trick and works great. Thanks so much and sorry for the late reply - this is awesome ! :)